# How should low-rep users approach issues that could be solved by permissions they don't have access to?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users

As a new, low-rep user I often find issues that I struggle to help with due to not having access to permissions that would be able to easily address the issues, for example:

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653658/get-broadcast-calendar-month-function) which at the time was still active, the flags I currently have access to for this would were:

[image: Flags given (Spam, Offensive, or Other)]

It seemed that 'other' would be the most appropriate, in the flag I described the issue at hand

> User has made no effort to solve the problem, question is vague and merely a request rather than a question to solve. – Aaron Critchley 27 mins ago

My flag was afterwards declined by a mod with the message:

> declined - Please use standard close votes or close flags for this instead of flagging for moderators.

Which I do not have access to, and therefore, cannot use.
 As a side note for this particular example a mod soon came in to close the question with the comment:

> At this point, this could be written any number of ways and you've showed absolutely no attempts at solving this problem, so I'm closing this. –  bluefeet♦ 25 mins ago

This seems remarkably similar to the comment I gave on my flag. Is this simply irrelevant or does it take away from the validity of the declination of my flag?

Another example would be when a question is too vague, where users with the appropriate rep can comment in an attempt to extract information, or encourage the user in the right direction, low rep users would be left to either edit, flag, answer or ignore. (I understand this is far less of an issue on the ground it only requires 50 rep to comment, but the principle still stands.)

Generally speaking, is it be better for the low-rep user to ignore the question or should they take the best approach they have available, knowing there are other, better approaches that they personally cannot take?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please don't use custom moderator flags to draw attention to things that can be handled by the community. A lot of people have close-vote privileges. When one person casts a close vote or selects one of the standard close reasons from the flag menu, it goes into a review queue for a very large community to look at. When you use a custom flag, it goes to the diamond moderator queue where only a handful of people can see it. That particular queue currently has a backlog of over 1000 flags. If you don't have the reputation to vote to close and you don't see the option on your flag dialog, please don't do anything. Someone with more privileges will be along shortly.

Comment: Thank you for your input, in extension, does this generally hold true for any other occurrences where a better solution would be available at a higher 'rep level'? If not, what are the scenarios where I should take an objectively sub-par approach due to not having access to better ones?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you're ahead of the curve in understanding the community, but most people with 19 rep do not understand what should be closed and not, which is a big driver for having the reputation system in the first place. (Heck, many with more rep don't understand it either, but that's a separate issue)

I'd say ignore it. Earn the rep, then you can start casting close votes as appropriate.