# What can low-rep users do to to reopen their questions that were incorrectly closed as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions, reputation, privileges

I asked [a question about handling email in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540853/email-piping-to-php-correctly-handling-attachments), which unfortunately was very quickly sidetracked as a 'possible duplicate'. I am sure people are likely to read the title or first line and do the same to this one (a part of the problem I am trying to seek advice on).

Once enough people read the [duplicate] marker in the name, they seem to simply take a fast look and then assume that it is correct and also mark it as duplicate. So now I have this facing me;

[image: Duplicate Banner]

The issue is that as a 'low-reputation' user I have no way of removing the [duplicate] mark, and as such people seem to assume its accuracy and continue on without bothering with the question.

I have since edited to clarify my question further, including additional research I have put in since the original question was asked. However, there's not so much as a hint of comments or answers that would usually occur on questions. Obviously I attribute this to the [duplicate] tag.

**tl:dr**
How are low-reputation users meant to deal with this? I certainly don't intend on re-posting it, that would be a literal duplicate and simply a waste. Other questions about this simply have replies saying to edit it, as is suggested in the yellow text box, or vote to re-open. I don't have any re-open or similar privileges.

I came across [How should low-rep users approach issues that could be solved by permissions they don't have access to?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290323/how-should-low-rep-users-approach-issues-that-could-be-solved-by-permissions-the) as well, which is somewhat relevant to my query here today. However the 'privilege' needed here is of more direct consequence to me as a user. While I understand why reputation earns these privileges to ensure that new users can't just come in and start abusing them, the ability to resolve an issue that had a question marked as duplicate should be one afforded to almost every user, assuming they aren't BRAND NEW.

I strongly feel that the question and its 'duplicate' are not alike, and while other questions can also be marked as duplicate, the detail I am asking for is not found within them. (This is of course my own opinion and may not reflect how the community chooses to shed light on it.)

Furthermore, it seems to me that a lot of users are very quick to jump to such conclusions. I also had a user practically accuse me of wanting to leech code and have someone do the work for me. I ALWAYS, as do most legitimate users, ask for explanations so I can increase my understanding, not just copy and paste. These assumptions lead to closed/locked/duplicate questions. What is the best way, once more as a low-rep user, to be handling this in the future? Should I reword the question in a specific manner?

Comment: You did right thing that you edit question so user can vote for reopen. And in comment clarify that how your question is not duplicate of that one. And at last wait for 5 reopen vote.

Comment: So am I to assume that my presumption of "Sit here and wait for the best" is the only course of action? If not enough vote then I could never get an answer?

Comment: The duplicate kind of answers your question, albeit not in a lot of detail. It's not totally satisfactory, agreed

Comment: If your question is good and you show what you have tried but still you have issue/problem then sure you get answer. Upto now you already get 2 reopen what. And yes if want answer then you should wait for best answer. From next time in your question mention  you refer link and write you have tried those but didn't get solution.

Comment: Very, very closely related: [Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194476)

Comment: Note that the "[duplicate]" in the title is not added until the question is actually closed. Furthermore, until it's closed, [you're the only one who sees the banner at the top](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate).

Comment: Thank you Josh, I was unaware of that. I had strong fears that the [duplicate] tag would simply have users overlook it, as I would assume my own behavior would be in the same scenario.

Comment: You should read the duplicate question, read through *all answers* (not just the selected!), try what it says, and update your question with details about what you got from that question and why it didn't work.  A sentence usually isn't enough to prove non-duplicateness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the real world, your question would be fine. If you were a colleague or friend asking I'm sure  most people would be happy to answer it.

However, Stack Overflow has developed a very narrow focus over the years, and become rather intolerant of questions that doesn't fit this focus.

For one, questions that are actually *two* questions are [strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-asks-many-things).

For another, "Is this code the right way to do X?" type questions tend not to get great responses.

This has several reasons. They take a *lot* of effort and analysis to answer, plus they are very specific to *your* situation. That is not in line with SO's mission of creating an archive of canonical questions and answers that are useful to others. The site is not intended to be a help and tutoring forum.

Whether this sometimes harsh attitude is a necessary act of quality control in light of more than 7,000 new questions a day, or unnecessary bureaucratic meanness, or something in between, depends on who you ask.

Your second question, "how do I deal with attachments?", *is* answered in the linked duplicate question, so formally, the closing was arguably OK.

However, the answer is not exactly brimming with detail. Had I been involved in the closing I might have voted to keep your question open, and edit it into shape instead, to invite better answers.

In its current form, though, your question will always face difficulties, and I don't think it would be right to reopen it unedited.

To try and help you out, I have started a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624121/how-do-you-extract-attachments-when-piping-mails-to-php), and edited its title, to see whether it can attract more detailed answers - possibly with code samples.

Alternatively, do check out the hints in the existing answer: PEAR::Mail::Mime::Decode is a viable way to go, as are other libraries that can decode a MIME mail.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification and of course your attempt to assist, I will ensure I watch that question and hope that something more informative comes of it. My intent here isn't to copy and paste but to understand. I find the PHP manual to be useful, but the users here to give a much better explanation (even without full coded answers) allowing me to UNDERSTAND and not just execute the code.